# Ensuring table cell does not expand to fit image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

So I've been experiencing some issues getting the container that an image is in to not expand to fit this image.

Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

**With divs**

```
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
```

```css
div{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**Or if you want to use a table:**

```
table td{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you can re-position the image within the div or table using `margin`

[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/thTQW/1/)

[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/thTQW/3/)

Comment: Is there a way to allow overflow and still not have the images parent container expand?